# Vercel giving 404 error when using a custom URL

Tags: javascript, vercel, vite

I am developing a code playground. Everything works in **my computer**,
It has a saving system. *Encodes* your code and puts it in the **URL**. When page loads, gets the code from the URL. It works perfectly fine. It uses **Vite**, vanilla JS, and I used the Vite setting on Vercel, but the saving system doesn't work. When you reload, instead of getting the code, It gives a 404 error message, as the URL isn't on the dist folder.
*What can I do?*
**Complete code:** https://github.com/L1ghtingBolt/codeebox/

Comment: there's no vercel.json in your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add vercel configuration to your root directory.

vercel.json

```
{
  "rewrites": [{ 
      "source": "/(.*)",
      "destination": "/" }]
}
```